# enthought installing problems

Tags: python, enthought

I contact you because I am trying to install EPD so that I can run the following software (http://code.google.com/p/spikepy/wiki/Installation#Mac). I downloaded the following installer of EPD from your website : 
epd-7.3-2-macosx-i386.dmg

But it seems that the Fameworks are not installing properly in the library, because when I try to install Spikepy (which depends on EPD) I get the following error: "ImportError: No module named wx"

Then when I write the command python, there is no mention of EPD, which I know it should be as I installed it on my previous computer, in stead I get the following message:

```
wl3s-246-58:spikepy-0.82 admin$ python
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jun 25 2011, 05:09:01) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

additionally when I search for the frameworks folder although it found it for 10 seconds after I installed EPD it, then seemed to disappear:

```
Last login: Thu Feb 7 11:16:50 on ttys000
wl3s-246-58:~ admin$ ls -lah /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 7B Feb 7 11:12 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python -> python2
wl3s-246-58:spikepy-0.82 admin$ s -lah /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python
-bash: s: command not found
```

Could you please help me figuring out what is wrong? and how can I get EPD to be installed properly on my computer?
My computer specifications are: Mac OSX version 10.7.5 1.7GHz Intel Core i5

thank you very much,
Best wishes,
Lucia

Comment: Sounds like you have some symbolic links to play with. Run `which python` and find the python you're actually calling---it should be in `usr\bin` or something. Once you know where that link is, just change it to point at the new python, see here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/creating-soft-link-or-symbolic-link/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are not using EPD, after all: the python command should display something like

```
Enthought Python Distribution -- www.enthought.com
Version: 7.1-2 (32-bit)

Python 2.7.2 |EPD 7.1-2 (32-bit)| (default, Jul 27 2011, 13:29:32) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
Type "packages", "demo" or "enthought" for more information.
>>>
```

Try adding this line to the `.bashrc` file in your home directory

```
export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:$PATH
```

then open a new terminal and try running `spikepy` again.